# Can User Profile Service read data from other sources such as SAP, Oracle or only through AD?

Tags: 2013, active-directory, user-profile-service

Can User Profile Service read data from other sources such as SAP, Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All LDAP compatible sources should work, so that is the first check you need to perform.

Here is the Technet article for User Profile Synchronization for 2013, complete with information regarding SAP, and other business systens; http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg188041.aspx#importBusiness

Here is a guide for setting up User Profile synchronization against a Sun system, for 2010 but might give you some information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tehnoonr/archive/2010/11/21/how-to-setup-user-profile-synchronization-between-sharepoint-2010-and-sun-ldap.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can create a connection through the BCS to any database or web service and then use that as a secondary import source for SharePoint User Profile Service.